# Error itgencun016: Waarschuwing itgendhb005: Connection not established. Application is being closed

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

Since yesterday, I get the following error in Data Hub when it runs our stock export on Exact Online:

```
Error itgencun016: Waarschuwing itgendhb005: Connection not established. Application is being closed.
```

The Invantive SQL script has not changed, and neither has the batch file. The script no longer outputs the stock overview.

The batch file contents are:

```
@echo off
rem
rem Script to run an Invantive SQL file with possible Invantive Data Hub scripting language statements.
rem
rem Please note that the encrypted password is bound to the PC used to generate this file.
rem When you want to run this batch file on another PC, please generate a new encrypted password at that PC.
rem
rem Created by Invantive Control for Excel on 11/11/2016 9:08:38 AM.
rem
rem $Id: $
rem

set INVANTIVE_PRG=C:\Program Files\Invantive Software BV\Invantive Data Hub 2016R1 stable channel (LNUMBER)\Invantive.Producer.QueryEngine.exe

set INVANTIVE_USR=Invantive

set INVANTIVE_PWD=SECRET

set INVANTIVE_CONN=Exact Online\EOL-ACME-COM

set INVANTIVE_SQL_FILE=c:\jobs\invantive-extract-stock-positions.sql

set INVANTIVE_LOG_FILE=c:\jobs\invantive-extract-stock-positions.log

set INVANTIVE_INTERACTIVE=False

"%INVANTIVE_PRG%" /user:"%INVANTIVE_USR%" /connection:"%INVANTIVE_CONN%" /password:"%INVANTIVE_PWD%" /file:"%INVANTIVE_SQL_FILE%" /logfile:"%INVANTIVE_LOG_FILE%" /logoverwrite:"%INVANTIVE_LOG_FILE_OVERWRITE%" /interactive:%INVANTIVE_INTERACTIVE%
```

What is wrong with the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your log file. This message only occurs when authentication was not successful, but since the log file is very detailed that message might not be shown.

It is probably something like:

```
Type: Invantive.Data.OAuthException
```

or

```
Warning itgenerr024: Your session has expired. (Or whatever translation)
```

On Exact Online, when the password or user or connection string is incorrect the error can be confusing. In general it indicates that user, password or connection string is wrong (specify the `apiUrl` to set the country).